# Bulk Post update_post_meta

Tags: posts, query, post-meta, publish, wp-update-post

how can use this code for update just post_meta ?

here my code :

```
function update_all_posts(){

    $args = array('post_type'=> 'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page'=>50
    );

    $published_posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($published_posts as $post_update){

       $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_update->ID,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
       );

       wp_update_post( $query, true );  
    }

}
```

i want use this code :

```
$value = 'HELLO';
update_post_meta($post_id,'test', $value);
```

Comment: Does the value correspond to a custom field in the post meta table/on on the post type?  If so, you'll need that field's machine name/slug to target the data for updating in a query.  Also, are all posts really to be assigned the static value of 1000, or assigned something dynamic each time the function is called?

Comment: tnx for replay.

i want use just update_post_meta() in the query :   wp_update_post(); in the all posts in my site

Comment: It's unclear WHERE you want to use update_post_meta. As it stands, if you have `$post_id` with the ID of a post, the code you posted works just fine. However, whether it solves whatever task you are trying to solve is another issue and really depends on the task (and you'll have to explain more about that task).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one function that I made for bulk post meta update that you can use.

```
/*
 * Optimized way to add multiple usermeta keys and values
 * @author Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
 */
if( !function_exists('bulk_update_post_meta') ) : function bulk_update_post_meta(int $post_id, array $meta_data) {
    global $wpdb;

    $transactions = 0;

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        $meta_data[$meta_key] = [
            'exists' => $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `{$wpdb->postmeta}` WHERE `post_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $post_id,
                $meta_key
            )) > 0,
            'value' => maybe_serialize($meta_value)
        ];
    }

    $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_object) {

        $meta_value = $meta_object['value'];

        if ( $meta_object['exists'] ) {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "UPDATE `{$wpdb->postmeta}` SET `meta_value` = %s WHERE `post_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $meta_value,
                $post_id,
                $meta_key
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        } else {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO `{$wpdb->postmeta}` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)",
                $post_id,
                $meta_key,
                $meta_value
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        }
    }

    $wpdb->query('COMMIT');

    clean_post_cache($post_id);

    return $transactions === count($meta_data);
} endif;
```

You simply put an array with `'meta_key' => 'Value'`

Example:

```
bulk_update_post_meta( $post_id, [
    'ivi_test__1' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__2' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__3' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__4' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__5' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__6' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__7' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__8' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__9' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__10' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__11' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__12' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
] );
```